# Queue Implementation using a Linked List

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list, queue

For understanding the concepts, I've implemented the `Queue` data structures using a linked list. Is there anything to improve?

**LinkList.java**

```
public class LinkList {

    private static class Node<T> {

        private final T data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data=data;
        }


        public void displayNode(){
            System.out.print(data+ " ");
        }

    }

    private Node first = null;
    private Node last = null;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (first == null);
    }

    public <T> void addLast(T data) {
        Node n = new Node(data);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            n.next = first;
            first = n;
            last = n;
        } else {
            last.next = n;
            last = n;
            last.next = null;
        }

    }

    public void removeFirst() {

            Node temp = first;
            if (first.next == null)
                last = null;
            first = first.next;

        }


    public void displayList() {
        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            current.displayNode();
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}
```

**LinkListQueue.java**

```
public class LinkListQueue {

    LinkList newLinkList = new LinkList();

    public <T> void enqueue(T data) {
        newLinkList.addLast(data);
    }

    public void dequeue() {
        if(!newLinkList.isEmpty())
            newLinkList.removeFirst();

    }

    public void displayQueue() {
        newLinkList.displayList();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return newLinkList.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

**LinkListQueueDemo.java**

```
public class LinkListqueueDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkListQueue queueImpl = new LinkListQueue();

        queueImpl.enqueue("A");
        queueImpl.enqueue("B");
        queueImpl.enqueue("C");
        queueImpl.enqueue("D");
        queueImpl.displayQueue();
        queueImpl.dequeue();
        queueImpl.displayQueue();

    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using Java 8 then consider [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) over `null`.

Comment: If you're implementing a queue, consider implementing Queue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**BUG:**

```
public void removeFirst() {

        Node temp = first;
        if (first.next == null)
            last = null;
        first = first.next;

    }
```

This crashes if you have an empty list. Add a check for `first == null`. Additionally... what's that `temp` variable for?

---

Don't define the Node as `T`, define the List to contain `T`.

```
public class LinkList<T>
```

This because you use the T outside the Node class and you ended up having to add it to the addLast method.

---

```
    if (isEmpty()) {
        n.next = first;
        first = n;
        last = n;
    } else {
        last.next = n;
        last = n;
        last.next = null;
    }
```

You already know that `n.next` is null. You also know that `first` is null, because that's what defines `isEmpty()`.

So instead, try this:

```
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = n;
    } else {
        last.next = n;
    }
    last = n;
    last.next = null;
```

It does the same thing.

---

Design:

You have an insert (enqueue) method... but there's no way to retrieve an object that went into the Queue. `removeFirst` could return the object. This drastically cuts down on the uses of such an object (it's useless now).